# Integral for 2-point function in $d$ dimension

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, integration, correlation-functions, propagator

When I was reading [Joao Penedones's TASI Lecture on AdS/CFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04948), it says in (104):
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\int \frac{d^dx}{z^{d-1}}\frac{z^\Delta}{(z^2+(x-y_1)^2)^\Delta}\partial \frac{z^\Delta}{(z^2+(x-y_2)^2)^\Delta}=\frac1{(y_1-y_2)^{2\Delta}}
$$
up to some finite normalization constants which can be found on the notes.

I wonder how one achieved this result. I tried Feynman parametrization, and then expand the term in $\int du$, where u is the Feynman parameter, by powers of $z$. However, the result only has the positive powers of $z$ if I assume $\Delta\geq\frac d2$.

edit:
I tried this solution: [AdS/CFT scalar 3-point function integral from Feynman parametrization?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377621/ads-cft-scalar-3-point-function-integral-from-feynman-parametrization)
I found it seems to be equivalent to Feynman parametrization.

Both methods yield an $(\textit{sth})((\textit{sth})(y_1-y_2)^2+z^2)^{\frac d2-2\Delta}$ term. Here $\textit{sth}$ are Feynman parateters.

So, on small $z$ expansion I got no $z$ dependence in the integral, but there's an $z^{2\Delta-d}$ outside the integral.

Thanks